# I'm trying to install dependencies in a React web app by running "yarn" but I get an "connect ECONNREFUSED" error

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg

```
yarn install v1.22.19
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel%2fhelper-builder-react-jsx: connect ECONNREFUSED 104.16.23.35:443".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/media/bkroland19/ROLAND/FINAL/ElectionDapp-main/client/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: Can we see the log that is in the error message?

Comment: What command did you run?

Answer (score 2):

This looks like an issue with your internet or your firewall. Make sure you can access `https://registry.npmjs.org/`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was about some vpn connection which was halting me from installing the dependencies , simply disconnect your vpn and boom it works again